# How to make .tcl file directly executable from Launcher

Tags: bash, launcher, tcl

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I use a program called ApE (A plasmid Editor) which I have to run directly from the Terminal using the following command;

```
tclsh8.5 /home/justin/ApE/AppMain.tcl
```

For convenience, I would like to be able to open this program directly as an executable icon embedded in the Launcher.  My expectation is that there should be a simple bash script I could write to call tclsh8.5 to open the .tcl file directly, but I am a complete novice and have no idea how to proceed towards this end.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @dobey I'm pretty sure my default desktop environment is Unity, and all the answers on that thread deal with GNOME.  Should I install the GNOME environment, or press on with the Unity?

Comment: The launchers are placed in the same location, using the same format, for either Unity, GNOME, or KDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete process of what I ended up doing;

```
$ sudo apt-get install gksu
$ cd /usr/share/applications
$ gksudo gedit ApE.desktop
```

Then I made the following .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=ApE
Icon=/home/justin/ApE/ApE.png
Exec=/home/justin/ApE/AppMain.tcl %f
Version=1.0
Comment=A Plasmid Editor
GenericName=Plamid Editor
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Categories=Utility;
StartupWMClass=ApE
StartupNotify=true
```

From there, I needed to modify the .tcl file by adding the following shebang to that script;

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
```

Then I made the .tcl script executable;

```
$ cd /home/justin/ApE
$ chmod +x AppMain.tcl
```

Then I validated and installed the .desktop with the following commands;

```
$ cd /usr/share/applications
$ desktop-file-validate ApE.desktop
$ desktop-file-install ApE.desktop
```

The desktop-file-install command added the following line to the .desktop file;

```
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

Then I needed to do a simple drag-and-drop of the ApE icon in the /usr/share/applications directory to the Unity Launcher, and there it was.

However, while this placed the ApE icon in the launcher, whenever I clicked the ApE icon, it created a question mark icon in the launcher to represent the open window.  To alleviate this, I needed to make the StartupWMClass values in agreement.  So back in terminal, I ran the following command;

```
$ xprop WM_CLASS
```

and then clicked on the open ApE window, which returned the following output;

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "dna_window18", "Toplevel"
```

So I went back into the ApE.desktop file;

```
$ cd /usr/share/applications
$ gksudo gedit ApE.desktop
```

and changed the StartupWMClass value to Toplevel, giving a final ApE.desktop file of

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=ApE
Icon=/home/justin/ApE/ApE.png
Exec=/home/justin/ApE/AppMain.tcl %f
Version=1.0
Comment=A Plasmid Editor
GenericName=Plamid Editor
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Categories=Utility;
StartupWMClass=Toplevel
StartupNotify=true
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

And that fixed it completely.